# Fetch POST puts payload into the name of the object

Tags: post, fetch, react-fullstack, x-www-form-urlencoded

Hey i'm try to pass data from my browser, which uses React, to my API - which then manages the database. I can only get the API and database to work via Postman because when i Fetch POST the payload, it puts the payload into the name of the response object.

response = '{"username":"lolawdawd","email":"wadwa","password":"xiCm9RDsi8YM6vE"}': ''

This then stops the api from making use of the data. I've tried many different methods and cannot figure this out. My code for Fetch is as follows:

```
 
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const input = {
      username: user,
      email: email,
      password: pass
      }
    
    console.log(input);
    try {
      await fetch(`http://localhost:8000/api/register`, {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify({
          username: user,
          email: email,
          password: pass
          }),
        headers:{
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      }})
      navigate('/login');
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err.message);
    }
    
  };
```

Comment: You are sending a wrong “Content-Type” header, in your case it needs to be “application/json”. And where do you assign the value of response?

Comment: @Teivaz Thanks for your response. The value is assigned to req.body. I've tried to use "application/json" but it doesn't send the data to the api when i do that. The only way that data gets sent in any way, is using "x-www-form-urlencoded". Postman works when i use urlencoded too. 
I don't see why it wouldn't send via json? It always shows as undefined.